# Kraken Exchange API: AddOrder's expiretm parameter

Tags: api, currency, finance, trading

Does the API `AddOrder()` command support `expiretm` for limit orders? I always get an `EGeneral:Invalid arguments:expiretm` error when I set this parameter.

I tried to expire 3 seconds from now with the following settings:

```
1) expiretm = 3             # int
2) expiretm = "+3"          # string
3) expiretm = 1500226507    # int
```

No luck, all return the mentioned error. Only `expiretm = 0` is accepted.

- Is `expiretm` supported for limit orders?
- Which syntax is the right one: (1) or (2)?

Thx

Comment: I tried the same thing. Current time + 90 seconds works ok. Looks like kraken forbids placement of orders that expire after a few seconds. Pretty lame. Kraken is pretty shit all 'round. Use something else.

Answer (score 5):

The minimum relative value for `expiretm` is `+5`.

I found out by trail and error.

Answer (score 3):

I use a expiretm too on my order. Here is an example:

```
$res = $kraken->QueryPrivate('AddOrder', array(
    'pair' => $pair,
    'type' => 'buy',
    'ordertype' => 'limit',
    'price' => $price,
    'volume' => $volume,
    'expiretm' => '+180'
));
```

Comment: I am not the OP, but I had the same problem, and adding the '' solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

both `expiretm = 1500226507` and `expiretm = '1500226507'` are correct. However you must make sure `1500226507` is bigger than the current unix time. Also, make sure you are using the notation correct. It is too easy to make a mistake.  A correct usage could be, say

```
currentUnixTime = 1500226507
// set expiretm to a min from now
expirationTime = 1500226567 // notice the last two digits

blablabla{AddOrder{'pair: 'x', 'price: 'xx', 'volume: 'xxx', 'type: 'y', 'expiretm: expirationTime}};
```

BTW this is for nodejs.